# Get top 1 row from outer table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get only the first row from outer table.

I am trying to do something like the code below but getting an error. I cannot get the @rID =PartRequest.Id .

```
 declare @rID int
 SELECT     
   @rID =PartRequest.Id
   , Products.Name AS ProductName
   , PartRequestPhotos.Id AS PartRequestPhotosId
   , PartRequest.IsInsuranceClaimed
 FROM PartRequest 
 INNER JOIN PartRequestStatus ON PartRequest.PartRequestStatusId = PartRequestStatus.Id 
 INNER JOIN UsersInfo ON PartRequest.UserId = UsersInfo.aspnet_UserId 
 INNER JOIN Products ON PartRequest.ProductId = Products.Id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN PartRequestPhotos ON PartRequest.Id = 
      (select top 1 Id from  PartRequestPhotos where  PartRequestId =  @rID)
```

Comment: And what is your question? It seems like you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: what's the problem with your code?

Comment: I cannot get the  @rID from PartRequest.Id (@rID =PartRequest.Id)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get only the first row from outer table.

Enclose it in a subquery, instead of comparing it in the `JOIN` condition like so

```
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
   select top 1 Id from  PartRequestPhotos where  PartRequestId =  @rID
)   PartRequestPhotos ON PartRequest.Id = PartRequestPhotos.Id
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not get @rID, because of left join executed before presentation of the data, in order to do it you need to change query to following:

It is incorrect to assign only one variable, you either assign all columns to variables or non of them.

You need to use outer apply, to be able to call subquery for each row of the table on the left.

In order by you need to specify desc or asc, if you put asc it will get you the first id, desc it will return back the latest one.

```
        SELECT     
             PartRequest.Id
           , Products.Name AS ProductName
           , PartRequestPhotos.Id AS PartRequestPhotosId
           , PartRequest.IsInsuranceClaimed
         FROM PartRequest 
         INNER JOIN PartRequestStatus ON PartRequest.PartRequestStatusId = PartRequestStatus.Id 
         INNER JOIN UsersInfo ON PartRequest.UserId = UsersInfo.aspnet_UserId 
         INNER JOIN Products ON PartRequest.ProductId = Products.Id 
         OUTER APPLY
            (
              SELECT TOP 1 
                 Id
              FROM 
                 PartRequestPhotos
              WHERE 
                 PartRequestPhotos.PartRequestId = PartRequest.Id
              ORDER BY
                Id ASC
            ) PartRequestPhotos
```